# srand on php 5.3 produce unpredictable output

Tags: php, debian, php-5.3

This code on PHP 5.2 or 5.4 produce a predictable order, but on PHP 5.3 `srand(seed)` is ignored.

```
$n = date('YmdHi');
$a = explode('|','uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque');
printf("%s\n",$n);
print_r($a);
srand($n);
shuffle($a);
print_r($a);
```

More compact code (I expected the same number on the same minute, but on PHP 5.3 it doesn't works):

```
$n = date('YmdHi');
srand($n);
printf("%s\n",rand(1,100));
```

You can try different version on PHP here
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fromFunction/srand

**update**

@likeitlikeit According to documentation if you set a seed (with `srand()`) before `rand()`, `rand()` function should be return the same output for every run. This is useful when you want a predictable "rand" output based on an arbitrary integer (in my case the date).

This code should be produce the same output for every `$t` in `foreach`, but this doesn't seem works for all PHP versions. PHP 5.3 and 5.1 (I find out today) return different output foreach `$t`, like `srand()` was unset.

```
foreach(range(1,10) as $t){
    srand('20130605'); printf("| %s ",rand(1,100));
}
```

**PHP 5.4.x**

> | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40

**PHP 5.3.x**

> | 61 | 30 | 68 | 16 | 97 | 24 | 5 | 36 | 90 | 24

**PHP 5.2.x**

> | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40

**PHP 5.1.x**

> | 8 | 96 | 15 | 7 | 25 | 17 | 4 | 70 | 46 | 99

**PHP 5.0.x**

> | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So what's the question? We don't respond to infodumps - we *answer questions*. (It is acceptable and encouraged to answer your own question, but the answer needs to be **an answer**.)

Comment: **Q.** How can I make `srand` work under PHP 5.3? Is it a bug or a compliant behavior?

Comment: Why don't you actually post some output in reasonable amounts, showing the differences between the versions you mention?

Comment: PHP rand() is one of those functions that programmers incorrectly use in a security context.  So what you are seeing is likely the result of the PHP dev team bouncing between how rand() should behave between major releases.  If you really do need to do a Monte Carlo simulation, you might be better off implementing a generic LCG or Mersenne Twister in pure PHP to get around the inconsistencies in the native PHP implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you seed a random number generator (like rand) with a constant value, the output from `rand()` **might** be predictable.
Depending on the implementation, the output **might** be

```
| 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40
```

If you're repeatedly re-seeding the generator with the same value, then asking it to generate a random number with the SAME parameters each time, the output **might** be completely repeatable - but you shouldn't rely on this behaviour.

If you use `srand()` without any parameters, it specifically generates a random number to seed the generator with. This ensures each time your run `rand(1,100);` the generator is starting from a randomised seeded state, and will generate random output.

*If you don't know why you're seeding your random number generator, then you probably don't need to.*

On the PHP site it says this:

> [From version] 5.2.1  The Mersenne Twister implementation in PHP now uses a new seeding algorithm by Richard Wagner. Identical seeds no longer produce
>   the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This
>   behavior is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe
>   to rely upon it nonetheless.

So it is unsafe to rely on the random-number generator to produce the same output - if you need to rely on the output being different, use a different method. `srand()` is apparently supposed to be a Random number generator, and not a Pseudo-Random number generator. Determinism is not guaranteed.

Comment: Sorry, but the statement "Identical seeds no longer produce the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior is not expected to change again" it's wrong. On multiple versions *after* 5.2.1 identical seeds produce indentical outputs.

Comment: That's the quote from the PHP site - apparently they change their mind about this more often than they update the documentation. All that we can guarantee is that we mustn't rely on this output being deterministic.